# SQL XML How to query specific node

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I'm playing around with `SQL` and `XML`.
I have a column in our database (`properties`) where `XML` is stored.

An example of this XML looks like this:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.xyz.de/activerepository/fileprops">
  <props>
    <prop ns="ARM:" elem="_NoFilter">
      <value xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</value>
    </prop>
    <prop ns="DAV:" elem="displayname">
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Some text in it</value>
    </prop>
    <prop ns="DAV:" elem="getcontenttype">
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">message/rfc822</value>
    </prop>
    <prop ns="DAV:" elem="creationdate">
      <value xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2017-01-02T09:38:28.1278078</value>
    </prop>
  </props>
</root>
```

I've written a query, where I get all props of this XML structure.

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.xyz.de/activerepository/fileprops')
SELECT 
    cast(properties as xml).query('root/props/prop'),
    *
FROM   tm_cas_files (nolock)
where  id = 'A7ED7D99-8CDB-47F6-8EF5-18E7FCB97F28'
```

This query works fine, but I get all nodes of the XML structure.

The result of this query looks like this:

```
<p1:prop xmlns:p1="http://www.xyz.de/activerepository/fileprops" ns="ARM:" elem="_NoFilter">
  <p1:value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</p1:value>
</p1:prop>
<p2:prop xmlns:p2="http://www.xyz.de/activerepository/fileprops" ns="DAV:" elem="displayname">
  <p2:value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xsd:string">Some text in it</p2:value>
</p2:prop>
<p3:prop xmlns:p3="http://www.xyz.de/activerepository/fileprops" ns="DAV:" elem="getcontenttype">
  <p3:value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xsd:string">message/rfc822</p3:value>
</p3:prop>
<p4:prop xmlns:p4="http://www.xyz.de/activerepository/fileprops" ns="DAV:" elem="creationdate">
  <p4:value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2017-01-02T09:38:28.1278078</p4:value>
</p4:prop>
```

How can I get now only a specific node of this XML?

I've already tested this query (to get i.e. "_NoFilter" node), but this SQL query returns no / empty result:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.xyz.de/activerepository/fileprops')
SELECT 
    cast(properties as xml).query('root/props/prop[elem="_NoFilter"]'),
    *
FROM   tm_cas_files (nolock)
where  id = 'A7ED7D99-8CDB-47F6-8EF5-18E7FCB97F28'
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ehm, why is my question marked as duplicate? I've already saw this linked answer, but it did not help. So please explain, why this is a duplicate. Thanks

Comment: @Tomalak this above is not concern with link you have provided. so, i voted to reopen it as it is different.

Comment: @YogeshSharma You are right. Reopened.

Comment: Thanks for reopening!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the `_NoFilter` node, you can use XPath to select only this one.

```
/root/props/prop[@elem="_NoFilter"]
```

or maybe even

```
/root/props/prop[@elem="_NoFilter"]/value
```

shorthand:

```
//prop[@elem="_NoFilter"]/value
```

Answer (score 2):

If you already know the index of the item, one way is

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.xyz.de/activerepository/fileprops')
SELECT 
    @xml.query('root/props/prop[2]')
```

Or better you can use following SQL XML Query

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.xyz.de/activerepository/fileprops')
select
    val.value('.','nvarchar(100)') as [PropValue]
from @xml.nodes('/root/props/prop[@elem="_NoFilter"]/value') as p(val)
```

[image]